# Compiling in C Programming

Tags: c, compilation

I am having trouble compiling the program I recently started called format. I am getting the following errors:

```
format.c:7:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]
format.c: In function ‘main’:
format.c:11:27: error: expected expression before ‘!=’ token
format.c:14:10: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
format.c:14:3: error: missing terminating " character
format.c:16:1: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
format.c:16:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
format.c:9:10: warning: variable ‘n1’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

When I compile using gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -O2 -o format format.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
 { 
  int c, n1;
  n1 = 0;
  while ((c + getchar())) !=EOF
     if 
(c == 40'\n')
     ++n1;
      printf("%d\",n1);

}
```

Comment: Is your code really formatted like this?

Comment: Please, `int main(void)`, `return 0`

Comment: As a beginner, don't use `-O2`  at first for `gcc`. Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`). Only once your program has no bugs could you recompile it with `-O2` (e.g. for benchmarking purposes).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, n1 = 0;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF){
        if(c == 40 || c == '\n')
            ++n1;
        printf("%d",n1);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to C  working on a project and got that code from the textbook. When I typed in the other code still received errors compiling.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
  {
    int c, n1;
    n1 = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) !=EOF)
        if
(c == '\n')
        ++n1;
        printf("%d\n", n1);

}
```